# Business not appearing in Google maps at all

Tags: seo, google, google-maps, google-local-search

I'm having problems with listing my business on Google Places for Business. I wish I can send you a link to my business page but can't find it even if I type on google my business address!.

Anyway, the business web site associated with my Google business page is "[pressurecleaningandsealing.com](http://pressurecleaningandsealing.com/)". I used a domain forward from a GoDaddy domain (pressurecleaningandsealing.com) to "[aqua-pressure.net](http://aqua-pressure.net)". I can see that the way this forwarding is done is by showing the actual page in an iFrame inside the new domain.

I once did this before for another business and it worked great. It ranked up as soon as I did the forwarding from a domain that contained a couple of keywords I wanted to rank for and listed this domain on the Google Business page.

The weird thing is that my business doesn't appear at all on google results when I type "pressure cleaning and sealing near cooconut creek". Almost seems like the business is being banned for some reason.

I have a Google Webmaster Tools and it doesn't show any error. The domain is about 3 weeks old (the other business I mentioned above ranked up to first page the very same day I purchased the domain).

Comment: I'm surprised that when you did it before it did work.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with these different domains and iframe approach.

But I can tell you that Google does not consider the content in the iframe on pressurecleaningandsealing.com to be part of that site.  Google associates all that content with the site being iFramed.

There is no way Google will put that site on the map doing things this way.

Comment: Yep. What they are doing is SEO suicide.

Comment: Well I wasn´t really trying to iFrame it, but that´s what GoDaddy does when you try to do a "redirect". I was trying to basically change the domain name. Anyway I figured out the reason why the business is not there is not this but some kind of bug on Google Places.